# Google query to get all the answer from a given user?

Tags: discussion, api, data-analysis

I usually use: `q=oscar-reyes+site%3Astackoverflow.com`, but that yields bot questions and answers.

Does anyone have a way to identify only answers ? ( or only questions? )

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.html?page=1&pagesize=1000&userId=20654&sort=) gets you the first 1,000 answers.  The API will not provide more than 1,000 answers at one time.  You can probably increase the page to 2 for users who have more than 1,000 questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reference to the current API implementation of the answers request:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17037/unofficial-so-api-reference/17040#17040

(Linked to avoid having to update more than one place for API info)